# SQL Query members by profile fields Buddypress

Tags: buddypress, profiles, sql, members

i am trying to add a profile based search option into my existing plugin. my plugin already search members by distance within a certain radius and i want to add the option to filter results by profile fields.

what i am trying to do is getting the user id that has the matching values entered in the search form.
i am trying something like:

```
SELECT user_id FROM {$bp->profile->table_name_data} 
WHERE (field_id1 = "field1" AND value1 = "value1")
AND (field_id2 = "field2" AND value2 = "value2")
AND (field_id3 = "field3" AND value3 = "valu3")
........
```

but this doesn't work. it will work with the WHERE clause only but not when i am adding the ANDs. i assume this is have something to do with joins maybe?

any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head... I can think of a plugin that does this:

http://buddypress.org/community/groups/bp-profile-search/

Perhaps this will provide you with a good starting point for what you're trying to get done.

Comment: Thank you FlashingCursor. I actually already dug in the "profile-search" plugin. i should have mentioned that. I can use the method that plugin uses but i thought i could maybe find a better way. That plugin runs SQL SELECT query against each field within the fields loop and then get the users that exist in all of them. i thought that maybe one Query would run better performance-wise. i might be wrong and if there was a better way i guess it would be already there in that plugin. However, if anyone can provide another way that would be great. Otherwise i guess i could go with the method above.